# Why Bibliography is empty?

Tags: bibliographies

I use TeXnicCenter. Using The Legrand Orange Book (LaTeX Template, Version 2.2 (30/3/17), when compiling the bibliography appears empty.

The commands used regarding bibliography are as follows.

1) Main file:

```
\chapterimage{}
\chapter*{Bibliografia}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Bibliography}}
\section*{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Books}
\printbibliography
```

2)Structure:

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
\usepackage{calc} % For simpler calculation - used for spacing the index letter headings correctly
\usepackage{makeidx} % Required to make an index
\makeindex % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing
```

3)Biliography

```
@book{book_key,
    address = {Boston},
    publisher = {Birhäuser},
    author = {Andreecu,Titu; Gelca, Razvan},
    title = {Mathematical Olympiada Challenges},
    year = {2009},
    volume = {1},
    series = {},
    edition = {1},
    pages = {},
    month = {}
}

@book{book_key,
    address = {Rio de Janeiro},
    publisher = {SBM},
    author = {Morgado, A C de O; Carvalho, J B P; Fernadez, P},
    title = {Combinatória e Probabilidade},
    year = {2004},
    volume = {},
    series = {},
    edition = {2},
    pages = {},
    month = {}
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete example that compiles. Otherwise we can only guess. E.g., do you have any `\cite` commands in your document? If not, the bibliography will remain empty. Or: did you (or TeXstudio) run `pdflatex` + `biber` + `pdflatex` + ... ? If not, the bibliography will remain empty.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 contains a lovely explanation why you need to run Biber and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 contains guidelines for setting up your editor to run Biber for you. If you allow me a short comment I think that the bibliography code in the template is all over the place. It sets options that are not needed (e.g. `hyperref=true`, especially in a template) and doesn't use `biblatex`'s interface for the bib heading.